# Pass declare table variable to another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am sure the answer is *NO*, but I'll ask the expert anyway ;)

I've declared a table variable in my stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @OrderMapIds TABLE
(
    OrderId INT NOT NULL,
    NewOrderId INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @OrderMapIds (OrderId, NewOrderId)
SELECT [OrderId], [OrderId] FROM [tblOrder]
...
...
...
EXEC [AS.uspOrder_MoveOrder] @OrderMapIds = @OrderMapIds;  --I need to move order ids based on the mapped id
```

I need to pass `@OrderMapIds` to `[AS.uspOrder_MoveOrder]`. The question is how?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [AS.uspOrderItem_CopyRecord]
(
    @OrderMapIds AS TABLE -- This thrown error
)
AS
BEGIN
    ...
    ...
    ...
END;
```

**Now, I can accomplish this problem using Table-Valued Parameter (*TVP*)**. But if I could pass it without TVP, then it will be better (so I don't have to create TVP for small stuff).

Now, after looking at Google, I am sure the answer is *NO* (ie. I need to create *TVP* to accomplish task above). But I thought to ask the question in hope I might have missed something.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The answer is indeed No.

In SQL Server, the only way to pass a table to a stored procedure is using a user defined table type.

You do have some confusion in the terms, though.
*TVP* is the parameter itself - so even if you could just pass any table variable a stored procedure - it would still be a *Table Valued Parameter*.

What you want to avoid (but can't) is a *User Defined Table Type*.

If this was allowed, you would end up with a stored procedure that takes in a table valued parameter with an unknown structure - And this could lead to errors, extremely cumbersome code, and worst of all - silently using the wrong data.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

An interesting alternative, especially when the table structure is variable/dependent will be to convert data as JSON/XML ( data type for parameter will be NVARCHAR).

Way to go in your example will be

```
DECLARE @OrderMapIds NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT [OrderId], [OrderId] FROM [tblOrder] FOR JSON PATH

);
...
...
...
EXEC [AS.uspOrder_MoveOrder] @OrderMapIds = @OrderMapIds;
```

Comment: very interesting.  +1 for sharing... But how would you decode `@OrderMapIds` inside procedure `[AS.uspOrder_MoveOrder]`?.

Comment: SQL Server has built in methods to deal with xml, and since 2016 version also to deal with json. This is a good alternative to deal with an unknown data structure.